Is there a way to quickly find all the REST API backend endpoints used on the frontend of the same application?
In order to secure access to some endpoints (on Java back-end) I need to find all the endpoints used by a particular module of the UI (Angular JS frontend to be more specific), is there some tool to analyze the code and tell me where the frontend calls the backend endpoints, the endpoints themselves and some context preferably too?
Ideally, I would like to see it already in IntelliJ IDEA (I couldn't find it there, but maybe I didn't look hard enough), but an external tool would be better than doing it manually too
The general idea is that I need a tool that's doing something like Swagger, but for the frontend

Have you tried Find in Files/grep for url segments? E.g. if your API is under a common domain or common path (like example.com/hello or /myapi/...). Part of this (in your own codebase) is managing those endpoints, ideally with some form of centralized implementation. Hooking that implementation can let you dump the registered endpoints, at least.

@Rogue unfortunately, every url starts with different segments, some with variable values even, some with /, and some without, it's truly chaotic

Dump all endpoints in angular to front.txt -> dump all endpoints in your Java backend to back.txt -> sort the two files -> comm -12 front.txt back.txt to get all matching lines. You might need to filter a little to exclude things like url parameters. Not aware of a tool that'll do this out of the box, but not impossible to make (and then distribute as FOSS so others can benefit!). You'll likely need to search ahead to find some commonalities to ensure you're covering all endpoints in your search. This might not be worth the effort for, say, <50 endpoints, vs. just doing it yourself.

You can also set a central method (like makeURL) in your codebase that everything utilizes (and convert new ones as you find them). Then at runtime you can dump any found URLs. There's plenty of ways to gather your information, but again I'm not aware of an out-of-the-box tool for one (and such questions are off-topic on SO).
